# I am trying to fix this error but nothing is working

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have an error with web packs and nextjs.

```
import NextDocument, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import theme from '../libs/theme.js'

export default class Document extends NextDocument {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head />
        <ColorModeScript initialColorMode={ theme.config.initialColorMode }  />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

Error: ReferenceError: Cannot access '**WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT**' before initialization.

```
   9 |   <Head />
> 10 |   <ColorModeScript initialColorMode={ theme.config.initialColorMode }  />
     |                                      ^
  11 |   <body>
  12 |     <Main />
  13 |     <NextScript />
```

Does anyone know a fix? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only child elements `html` can have are `head` and `body`. You cannot have any other children; you must put all other stuff into either of those two.

Comment: But I am following a tutorial, and on his site it works just fine..

Comment: Maybe you should import ColorModeScript component from somewhere

Comment: It is imported, I see I didn't paste it above..

Comment: @Meijerrr Show file structure and ColorModeScript component

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above try moving your script into the `<body>` (or into the `<Head/>`)

```js
<Head />
<body>
  <ColorModeScript initialColorMode={ theme.config.initialColorMode }  />
</body>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work..